# Why is a version string with two dots prohibited in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

Both Android and iOS does support that version (name) format but why not CN1? I would like to express the patch version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's misleading. The implementation on iOS/Android is radically different e.g. in Android this is just a display value and the actual version is really an integer.

You can customize the display versions manually using build hints specifically `android.versionCode` & `ios.bundleVersion` from https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html

Comment: I already use that approach (setting the version number / code separately for each platform). But in addition to that I would like to name the version in the X.Y.Z format without having to do this for each platform independently. Wouldn't it make sense that CN1 accepts the X.Y.Z format and convert it to an appropriate code under the hood (as you already do for X.Y)?

Comment: as I stated the version naming by the X.Y.Z format is supported on both platforms natively

Comment: in the current situation I'm forced to for example to set my new build's version to (at least) 2.2 if I want to patch a published build (with version label 2.1), although the changes are only based on bug fixes. If I try to upoload my build with version label 2.1 but a higher bundleVersion I get the following error:

Comment: ERROR ITMS-90186: "Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '2.1' is closed for new build submissions" ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [2.1] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [2.1].". Thus incrementing the bundleVersion is not solving the issue!

Comment: As I said the concept of minor update literally doesn't exist in Android where the version number is an integer. So no that wouldn't be realistically possible. You are referring to this issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1405 which is a bug. We fixed it then got one comment which was somehow missed in 2015 with no followup. Unsurprisingly this got lost. Doing 3 points in a generic way isn't technically practical

Comment: all apps (either from iOS or from Android) I'm aware of do use the 2 dots format and I think this makes sense. I didn't get the point why this shouldn't be allowed and why this would cause an issue in the crossplatform manner. I know that at the end on Android the versionCode is relevant but it's fact that most publishers, whether on iOS or Android, use two dots in the version label since it's semantically more precise.

Comment: actually my issue differs from github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1405 since in my case I'm forced to change the CFBundleShortVersionString (even though I've already changed the bundle version) as the application loader doesn't accept the upload otherwise. It's not about testflight in my case. Since I only did bug fixing I would prefer to set the version label as "2.1.1" but this isn't possible in CN1.

Comment: It's relevant because there are some nuances to the 3 dot versioning system that don't translate between OS's when we translate the code. So you want the `ios.minorVersionNumber` value too which was added & removed. You can file an RFE for that